# Linking two tables

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two tables in two different workbooks. I want to let a table read from the other one.
When I type this formula:

```
=COUNTIF('[Workbook1.xlsx]Form1'!$G:$G,[@Name])
```

It works, but when I type:

```
=COUNTIF('Workbook1.xlsx'!Table1[@Name],[@Name])
```

It doesn't work

I need to use the second formula properly without using the whole column, how can I do this? Sometimes, I have two tables in the same sheet below each other, and I need the second formula.

Comment: Without testing, it looks like the second formula should include `Table1[Name]` instead of `Table1[@Name]` if you want to reference the whole column. There may be more to it than that. You can always add cell references by clicking to select and it'll input whatever is correct into the formula automatically.

Comment: More explanation:  `@` is a modifier of the column to refer to the current row. so be careful not to remove it from the second `[@name]` (in case you didn't carefully read the comment by @EngineerToast) and removed both of them.

Comment: @attavip ,,, better use Data Relationship method & then create a Pivot Table !!

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable comments